# Behavior of pointers

Tags: go

I am trying to understand the behavior of pointers and I am confused with what can be observed here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    name string
}
type PersonSpecial struct {
    name *string
}

func MapPersonToNewPerson(p *Person) *PersonSpecial {
    fmt.Printf("Inside Special Person Mapper: %+v\n", &p)
    dummy := &PersonSpecial{
        name: &p.name,
    }
    fmt.Printf("Inside Special Person Mapper Lower: %+v\n", dummy)
    return dummy
}
func createPerson(name string) Person{
    return Person{name: name};
}
func main() {
        persons :=[]Person{createPerson("One"), createPerson("Two")}
    persons2 :=[]*PersonSpecial{}

    for _, person := range persons {
        dummy := MapPersonToNewPerson(&person)
        fmt.Printf("Inside First Loop: %+v\n", dummy)
        persons2 = append(persons2, dummy)

    }
    for _, person1 := range persons2 {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", *person1.name)
    }
}
```

```
Inside Special Person Mapper: 0x1040c130
Inside Special Person Mapper Lower: &{name:0x1040c128}
Inside First Loop: &{name:0x1040c128}
Inside Special Person Mapper: 0x1040c150
Inside Special Person Mapper Lower: &{name:0x1040c128}
Inside First Loop: &{name:0x1040c128}
Two
Two
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JNSXOoQIbty

Why am I getting the same address for both persons although I am passing them by reference? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong here?" Yes, basically all of it. In line 15 you are printing the address of an address: p is a pointer and &p the address of this pointer; &p is of type **Person. Line 29 and 30: person in the for loop is a loop variable and is _reused_ in each loop iteration, only its value changes. It's address is always the same (and so the address of its name field). This results in line 16 assigning the same address to all new dummys (the address if the loop variable).

Comment: Rule of thumb 1: never take the address of a loop variable. Rule of thumb 2: Never think of a pointer as a reference; it is not.

Comment: Some more comments: func createPerson is unnecessary, it is even more to read and write than a simple Person{"One"} which is clearer. MapPersonToNewPerson has no need to take a *Person as argument and it is unclear why you return a *PersonSpecial. Start simple: func MapPersonToNewPerson(p Person) PersonSpecial. Print pointer values with the %p verb instead of %+v of Printf (to be precise).

Comment: Line 27: persons2 has way to many unnecessary indirections: It is a slice of pointers of structs containing a pointer to string. There is basically no benefit ever of using a *string (except to differentiate "unset" from "empty").

Comment: Thanks @Volker, that was really helpful! May be you should add it as answer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the misunderstanding of this statement:

> "for _, person := range persons {"

"person" is variable of type Person. In this 'for' statement value of persons[0] is copied to "person" variable. Effectively the next statement, "dummy := MapPersonToNewPerson(&person)", takes the pointer of same variable and adding it twice in to persons2.

When the for loop executes for the second time, the content is "person" variable is updated with persons[1].

Son the last 'for' loop, the content of the same pointer is printed twice.
If you print the pointer value of person1.name in second for loop, you will see the pointer values are same for both the elements.

> "fmt.Printf("%p, %+v\n", person1.name, *person1.name)"